# How to keep transparency on a custom painted Checkbox control

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, checkbox

I have the problem to create an owner drawn checkox as I don't like the check styles. Subclassing the Winform checkbox is not the big deal and overpainting the checkbox itself easy. But I don't like the position of the text as there are no properties for positioning it.

So basically, clear the control's graphic, paint the checkbox AND the text how and where I like.

Just, not working as clearing the graphic results in a black rectangle and you loose the transparency. But without clearing or overpainting client area, original text will always overlap owner drawn text.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found now, is to set control's text to `string.empty`, call the base OnPaint method and override the OnTextChange event. That's it. Now I can draw the text exactly how I want and control is still transparent:

```
    class mycheckBox
    {
        private string _Text;

        protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
         // Prevent calling paint method on text change
        }

       protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
       {
        _Text = this.Text;
        this.Text = string.empty;
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Text = _Text; 

        // do your drawing here
        }
    }
```